# Deleting all nested JSON arrays except the one with the minimum date

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON dictionary.
What I would like to do is delete all "close_approach_data" objects of which the "orbiting_body" is not "Earth". 
The thing is there may be more than one object with orbiting_body: "Earth" and between all those I try to keep the one with the minimum "approach_date".

```
data = [
  {
    "id": "01",
    "close_approach_data": [
      {
        "orbiting_body": "Earth",
        "approach_date": "1945-06-07"
      },
      {
        "orbiting_body": "Earth",
        "approach_date": "1975-06-07"
      },
      {
        "orbiting_body": "Mars",
        "approach_date": "1935-06-07"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "id": "02",
    "close_approach_data": [
      {
        "orbiting_body": "Earth",
        "approach_date": "1945-06-07"
      },
      {
        "orbiting_body": "Earth",
        "approach_date": "1975-06-07"
      },
      {
        "orbiting_body": "Mars",
        "approach_date": "1935-06-07"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to get this :

```
data = [
  {
    "id": "01",
    "close_approach_data": {
      "orbiting_body": "Mars",
      "approach_date": "1935-06-07"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "02",
    "close_approach_data": {
      "orbiting_body": "Mars",
      "approach_date": "1935-06-07"
    }
  }
]
```

So I am trying to come up with some code:

```
earthObjs =[]
for element in data:
    for subel in element["close_approach_data"]:
        if ([subel][0]["orbiting_body"]=="Earth"):
            #then i would have to store the objects
            earthObjs.append([subel])

    #here i am trying to find the object with the min 'approach_date'
    minEarth = min(dt.strptime(earthObjs["close_approach_date"],"%Y-%m-%d"))

    #then i would have to somehow place this as the only element of close_approach_data
    element["close_approach_data"] = json.loads(minEarth)

    #and clear the earthObjs list so it can be used for the next element
    earthObjs.clear()
```

I know very well that half of my code doesn't work. I think I might finally be close to getting it to work, I just really need some help. Specifically, I know I am doing something wrong when searching for the min, as I can't access the `'close_approach_data'` field of the object.
Also, I am not sure about the `json.load`s line either.

Comment: Please add the result for the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly straight-forward translation of the processing you described into code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json

for dataset in data:
    earliest, initial = datetime.max, {}

    # Find the non-Earth body with the earliest approach date.
    for close_approach in dataset["close_approach_data"]:
        if close_approach["orbiting_body"] != "Earth":
            dt = datetime.strptime(close_approach["approach_date"],
                                   "%Y-%m-%d")
            if dt < earliest:
                dt, initial = earliest, close_approach

    # Replace entire close_approach_data list with a single object
    # comprised of the non-Earth item with the earliest date (or an
    # empty dictionary if there weren't any).
    dataset["close_approach_data"] = initial

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "01",
        "close_approach_data": {
            "orbiting_body": "Mars",
            "approach_date": "1935-06-07"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "02",
        "close_approach_data": {
            "orbiting_body": "Mars",
            "approach_date": "1935-06-07"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can implement your algorithm:

```
res = []

for d in data:
    res.append({**{'id': d['id'], **{'close_approch_data': \
    next((iter(sorted((e for e in d['close_approach_data'] \
                      if e['orbiting_body'] != 'Earth'), \
                     key=lambda x: x['approach_date']))), None)}}})

print(res)

[{'close_approch_data': {'approach_date': '1935-06-07',
                         'orbiting_body': 'Mars'},
  'id': '01'},
 {'close_approch_data': {'approach_date': '1935-06-07',
                         'orbiting_body': 'Mars'},
  'id': '02'}]
```

**Explanation**

At first sight (and second), this looks like a mess. But the essential parts are:

- Iterate your list of dictionaries.
- For each `id`, append an item to list `res`.
- Only include data not from Earth via an `if` clause within a generator expression.
- Sort by approach date; you can continue using `datetime`, but this is not necessary given the current format.
- Extract the first element if it exists via `next(iter(...))`. If no element exists, return `{'close_approach_data': None}`.